# Storing/retriving data to/from handles from helper function in a Matlab GUI created by GUIDE

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I made a GUI program to process and view images. I wrote some of the codes that are used more than once in helper functions those are called within the GUI function callbacks to make it more concise.

However, I've a trouble with saving changes to handles structure if I write my program in this way. The calculation in the helper function was done correctly when I examined it in debugging mode. But the changes to the handles structure was not updated.

I'm wondering of how I can fix this?

**Code :**

```
function ProcessData_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) % GUI callback
  val = get(handles.menu, 'Value');
  str = get(handles.menu, 'String');
  switch str{val}
    case 'Mode1'
      FRETCalculator1(handles);
    case 'Mode2'
      FRETCalculator2(handles);
  end

function FRETCalculator1(handles) % Helper function
  for indT = 1:size(handles.Data,1)
    for indZ = 1:size(handles.Data,3)
        handles.Data{indT,3,indZ} = handles.Data{indT,1,indZ}./(handles.Data{indT,2,indZ}+1);
    end
  end
  guidata(handles.mainGUI, handles);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of yours should actually save the changes :

```
guidata(handles.mainGUI, handles);
```

Now if you want to use the handles that were modified after calling your function, you have to actualize them :

```
FRETCalculator1(handles);
handles=guidata(handles.mainGUI);
% ...code using modified handles
```

Actually, handles are modified in the figure but not in the code executing after the function call.

I hope that was clear. :)

Comment: Yes. This indeed solved my problem! Thank you so much! You helped me clarified some concepts. I kept thinking that somehow the changes made to the handles after the function call ends are forever lost because there are two different copies of the handles and there are somehow some conflicts..
I came to a slightly different solution myself. I rewrite the helper function so that it has handles as its output. Then in the callback:
handles = FRETCaltulator1(handles);